# Vuetify text field inside loop loses focus after one input

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have the following Vuetify layout in my page:

```
<v-hover
  v-for="(prop, index) in obj.props"
  :key="prop"
  v-slot:default="{ hover }">
  <v-card flat tile
    width="120"
    class="mr-2 d-flex">
    <v-text-field single-line flat dense required
      v-model="obj.props[index]"
      type="number"
      label="Prop"
      height="30" />
    <v-fade-transition>
      <v-btn text icon small
        color="error"
        class="customPropCardRemove mt-2"
        :class="{ 'showCustomPropCardRemove': hover}"
        @click="removeCustomProp(obj, index)">
        <font-awesome-icon
          color="error"
          icon="times"
          class="fa-sm" />
      </v-btn>
    </v-fade-transition>
  </v-card>
</v-hover>
```

Basically it's a text field with adjacent button inside a card. The button fades in when hovering over the card. That works. However, the text field looses focus after a single input.

I thought maybe the v-hover/v-fade-transition somehow affects it, so I tried to remove it and keep the button constantly visible:

```
<v-card flat tile
  v-for="(prop, index) in obj.props"
  :key="prop"
  width="120"
  class="mr-2 d-flex">
  <v-text-field single-line flat dense required
    v-model="obj.props[index]"
    label="Prop"
    height="30" />
  <v-btn text icon small
    color="error"
    class="mt-2"
    @click="removeCustomProp(obj, index)">
      <font-awesome-icon
        color="error"
        icon="times"
        class="fa-sm" />
   </v-btn>
 </v-card>
```

But the issue still persists. Any ideas why is it happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I suspect the problem is in obj.props...is props an array?  If so, an array of what?

Comment: @ExcessJudgment Yes, it is an array of strings. And I have another button to push a new string (prop) when needed. Basically it can be something like that: `let objects = [{ id: 0, name: 'a', props: [] }, { id: 1, name: 'b', props: ['1', '24'] }]`

Comment: A code pen may help.  If the props array is pre-filled and not empty it may be causing the text field to lose focus because it is bound to the pre-declared values.

Comment: @ExcessJudgment OK, I tried to recreate it in Codepen, took me a while. I stripped any additional functionality (like dynamically adding props to objects or removing them), but the issue is recreated here with pre-populated props: https://codepen.io/igal-kleiner/pen/OJVXqww

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, I found what was causing this problem:

```
<v-card flat tile
  v-for="(prop, index) in obj.props"
  :key="prop"
  width="120"
  class="mr-2 d-flex">
  <v-text-field single-line flat dense required
    v-model="obj.props[index]"
    label="Prop"
    height="30" />
 .....
```

`:key="prop"` and `v-model="obj.props[index]"` are the same string. So once I input something in the text field - it causes the key to change, thus re-render the list and, consequentially, lose focus.
I changed `:key="index"` and it worked just fine.

Comment: Good to know.  List rendering of complicated/nested objects can be challenging.  The key change makes sense:  https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#key

Comment: awesome find.. thanks for adding this answer!